# Add UIImageViews to view - Auto Layout

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimageview, autolayout

I would like to add images depending on the st_pov. This code add one image. I need image below image, like list.

The code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < st_pov; i++)
    {
        picture_pov.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"picture_pov.png"];
        [pod_view addSubview:picture_pov];


        picture_pov.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

       NSLayoutConstraint *picture_constrant = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:text
                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                        relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                           toItem:picture_pov
                                                        attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                       multiplier:1
                                                         constant:-27];
        [pod_view addConstraint:picture_constrant];
}
```